# Splitting a string by \t - will successive tabs cause issues?

Tags: c#, parsing

I'm writing an automation program to parse a tab-delimited file and write the data into another program. Currently it takes each line of the file, splits it by tab, and uses the different entries in it's commands. My issues is that even though all the data entries I am parsing should have 'X' amount of fields, there are a good number of fields that are just empty, and sometimes there are tabs that will immediately succeed other tabs.

When I try and access the list of strings from the split file-line, I find myself sometimes getting an `IndexOutOfRangeException` quite frequently. Would the multiple tabs be causing my list to not always end up with 'X' amount of fields, and therefore throw this exception? If so, is there a way around this?

[EDIT]
Heres the code:

```
string[] parts = line.Split('\t');
String Organization = parts[0];
String SalesRep_FirstName = SalesRep.Split(' ').First();
String SalesRep_LastName = SalesRep.Split(' ').Last();
String Opportunity = parts[1] == "" ? "" : parts[1];
String Type = parts[6] == "" ? comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() : parts[6];
String CloseMonth = (parts[5].Split('/'))[0] == "" ? "12" : (parts[5].Split('/'))[0];
String CloseDay = (parts[5].Split('/'))[1] == "" ? "21" : (parts[5].Split('/'))[1];
String CloseYear = (parts[5].Split('/'))[2] == "" ? "2012" : (parts[5].Split('/'))[2];
String Stage = (parts[2].Split('-'))[0] == "" ? "1" : (parts[2].Split('-'))[0];
String Probability = parts[4] == "" ? "0" : (Math.Round(decimal.Parse(parts[4]) / 10) * 10).ToString();
String Source = parts[7] == "" ? "" : parts[7];
String Department = Type;
String Product = Opportunity;
String Revenue = parts[3] == "" ? "" : parts[3];
```

Ideally, each instance of the list `parts` will have 9 entries, (`parts[8]` is redundant, so its not referenced here)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That shouldn't be the problem, unless you're using `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries`.

For example:

```
string text = "a\t\t\tb";
string[] bits = text.Split('\t');
Console.WriteLine(bits.Length); // 4, of which the middle two are empty
```

If you can post the code which *isn't* working (in a short but complete form, ideally) that would help.

Comment: @Jordan: Okay, Well you're doing a *lot* of splitting there. For example, `parts[5]` might be empty, causing `CloseYear` to be incorrect. Basically, I don't think the problem is in the splitting by tabs... Do you log the data that you're having trouble with when an exception happens?

Comment: Sort of. This is my first winforms application, and I'm learning a lot as I go. I am doing some basic logging, but I doubt its going to provide much insight into the details of my issue. However, I do see what you mean with the splitting, so I'm going to take a look at that

Answer (score 6):

You can split a string in two ways:

```
string input = "x\t\ty\t\t\tz";

char[] separator = new char[] { '\t' };

string[] result1 = input.Split(separator, StringSplitOptions.None);
// result1 == new string[] { "x", "", "y", "", "", "z" }

string[] result2 = input.Split(separator, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
// result2 == new string[] { "x", "y", "z" }
```

If you're using StringSplitOptions.None, then the resulting array should always have the same length -- provided that each input contains the same number of tabs.